# Tweepy for Twitter API v2 - Extracting Additional Fields for Tweet Search

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, tweepy

I started playing around with Twitter API v2 in Tweepy. I've had some experience with v1 but it looks like it's changed a bit.

I'm trying to search tweets based on my query and later extract some meaningful information.
The code is following:

```
response = client.search_recent_tweets(
    "innovation -is:retweet lang:pl", 
    max_results = 100, 
    tweet_fields = ['author_id','created_at','text','source','lang','geo'],
    user_fields = ['name','username','location','verified'],
    expansions = ['geo.place_id', 'author_id'],
    place_fields = ['country','country_code']
)
```

Now, the issue is I'm not really sure how to read the output. I can easily access basic info with tweet object in the following way:

```
for tweet in response.data:
    print(tweet.text)
    print(tweet.lang)
    etc..
```

But how do I access other information, such as user_id for tweet object? As this information is in second list of response => `response.includes['user']`

There are no unique ids (at least I don't see them) to match this info with info from `response.data`

Below I'm adding an example output of my code. Response consists of iterables for data, includes, errors and meta. The thing is, the iterables don't seem to be always equal in size, meaning that I can't just take `data[0]` and `includes['user'][0]` etc.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

The response of the Twitter API looks like that:

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "...",
            "author_id": "2244994945",
            "geo": {
                "place_id": "01a9a39529b27f36"
            },
        }
    ],
    "includes": {
        "users": [
            {
                "id": "2244994945",
                "created_at": "..."
            }
        ],
        "places": [
            {
                "id": "01a9a39529b27f36",
                "country": "..."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So you should have in each tweet:

- The `author_id` field which is the `id` of the `User` object in the `includes` ;
- The `geo['place_id']` field which is the `id` of the `Place` object in the `includes`.

Comment: Hi, the thing is tweepy response is not formatted that way. It just returns list of iterables but I can't be sure the elements are index matching. I added output screenshot as an example.

Comment: @GKroch I don't understand your point since your edit show that the structure of the data is exactly the one that I described (except that there are more than one element per list, obviously). Do not forget that the default representation of the Tweepy classes does not show all the fields but only the ones that are always present.

Comment: Hi, what I'm confused about is if there are two lists with tweet details and user details. How do I know which user details correspond to which tweet? I once got one country information for 100 tweets. How do I know with this structure for which tweet this country was determined?

Comment: @GKroch Each tweet that has a geo information (but be carefull, they don't always have some!) will have a `"geo": {"place_id": "01a9a39529b27f36"}` field. Then, in the list of places located in the includes, you have to find which one has this id.

Comment: Hi, this makes sense. But when you look at my output, you'll see there is no key on which I can connect tweets with user info. Based on what you say, I'd expect to have user_id in data too, so that I can go, based on it, for other details to includes list. Am I missing something in my Python code then?

Comment: @GKroch Self quote: 'Do not forget that the default representation of the Tweepy classes does not show all the fields but only the ones that are always present.'. If you `print(response)`, it will show only the default fields that are always present. For example, you see that the `lang` field does not appear in the output, but you can `print(tweet.lang)`. And last thing, the user_id field in the data is called `author_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Tweepy is a great tool for working with Twitter API: I use it myself as well.
Under the hood the method you are using accesses the [search recent tweets api](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-recent#tab1)
As you can see in the Examples section, the API itself definitely provides an author id in the response data. Which means that Tweepy has it saved as well.

What you're actually seeing in the screenshot you've provided is the string representation of the Tweepy objects. This does not mean that the data is not there, however.

Here's a slightly modified version of your code:

```py
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client("YOUR BEARER TOKEN HERE")

response = client.search_recent_tweets(
    "innovation -is:retweet lang:pl",
    max_results = 100,
    tweet_fields = ['author_id','created_at','text','source','lang','geo'],
    user_fields = ['name','username','location','verified'],
    expansions = ['geo.place_id', 'author_id'],
    place_fields = ['country','country_code']
)

for tweet in response.data:
    print(tweet.author_id)      # print the author id of the tweet
    print(tweet.text)           # print the text
    print(tweet.data['lang'])   # print the language (PL, since we're filtering by it)
    print(tweet.data['source']) # what did the user use to publish the tweet?
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

When initializing your tweepy Client, set the return type to dict

```
client = tweepy.Client(
    bearer_token=bearer_token,
    consumer_key=api_key,
    consumer_secret=api_secret,
    access_token=access_token,
    access_token_secret=access_secret,
    return_type = dict
)
```

Then search_recent_tweets() will return a dictionary

Comment: `return_type = dict` is really useful